# Schengen Visa type?

Tags: schengen, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen.
I need to go to spain for 10 days to attend a summer school.

Flight details
 Delhi->munich->Bilbao

Bilbao->Munich->Frankfurt->Delhi

There is no overnight stay at any of the transit airports.
What type of Visa do I need?
Do I still need an airport transit visa?

Answer (score 5):

Both Spain and Germany are in the Schengen travel area. You will enter the Schengen area in Munich and go through immigration controls there, and leave again from Frankfurt. The flights from Germany to Spain are effectively domestic flights.

- You need a Schengen C visa, valid from the day when you land in Munich to the day you leave from Frankfurt.
- The visa will be issued by Spain, not Germany, because Spain is the main destination of your trip.

Comment: https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/transit-schengen-visa/  Here India is mentioned.

Comment: @metasj, you won't be passing *through* the international area of any Schengen airport. You will go through immigration and then fly from the domestic area.

Comment: @om,nice I get it.Also the application for visa appointment at Spanish embassy asks for the visa type-Tourist,business,airport transit or family member.Should I register as a tourist or business visa?

Answer (score 0):

You will not need an airport transit visa because you will have a short-stay type C visa.  You will enter the Schengen area in Munich and leave it in Frankfurt.  There will be no "systematic" passport control in Spain, though there is a chance that you'll encounter a less formal check.